# Set headphones as default sound output (defaults to HDMI)

Tags: 13.10, sound, hdmi, headphones

Ubuntu 13.10 on Lenovo U410.

The screenshot explains it best

[image]

after every reboot HDMI is selected as output device. I always have to switch to Headphones (which in fact are speakers and not headphones). They both work perfectly, but **how do I make Headphones the default?**. The UI doesn't offer any options for that.

## Hardware infos

```
$: sudo lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce 610M] [10de:1058] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)


$: cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0xeb610000 irq 46


$: cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0
Codec: Conexant CX20590
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x14f1506e
Subsystem Id: 0x17aa400b
Revision Id: 0x100003
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=4, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[3]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x10 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xc1d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="CX20590 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=7, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x11 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xc1d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Converter: stream=7, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x12 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x13 [Beep Generator Widget] wcaps 0x70000c: Mono Amp-Out
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x07, nsteps=0x07, stepsize=0x0f, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x07]
Node 0x14 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Control: name="Internal Mic Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Inverted Internal Mic Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=2, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Internal Mic Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Inverted Internal Mic Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=2, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="CX20590 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Converter: stream=4, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x17 0x18 0x23* 0x24
Node 0x15 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x17* 0x18 0x23 0x24
Node 0x16 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x17* 0x18 0x23 0x24
Node 0x17 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x30050d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x04, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x1a* 0x1b 0x1d 0x1e
Node 0x18 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x30050d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x04, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x1a* 0x1b 0x1d 0x1e
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Control: name="Headphone Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x0000001c: OUT HP Detect
  Pin Default 0x04211040: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Right
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400481: Stereo
  Control: name="Mic Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00001324: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x04a11030: [Jack] Mic at Ext Right
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00011334: IN OUT EAPD Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00: VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00010034: IN OUT EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400481: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000024: IN Detect
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400501: Stereo
  Control: name="Speaker Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10 0x11*
Node 0x20 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x12
Node 0x21 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x22 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x400001f0: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x21
Node 0x23 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40040b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Internal Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Internal Mic Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x04, stepsize=0x2f, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x90a60150: [Fixed] Mic at Int N/A
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x5, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x24 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20050b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10 0x11
Node 0x25 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
```

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: I've added some of the information. Any important ones I should add as well?

Comment: Still, every day I boot this thing and get a rage face when the audio comes from my monitor and I have to switch devices oO

Comment: It seems like 14.04 doesn't have this problem anymore, it keeps headphones selected between boots. I'm not posting this as an answer though, since it doesn't solve the 13.10 issue. But since 14.04 is LTS, you should just upgrade.

Answer (score 7):

### [**pavucontrol**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pavucontrol)

For a much better fine-tuning of our default audio setup we may install and run **pavucontrol** which also has an option to set a fallback device (below shown for a bluetooth headset):

[image]

If this does not work as expected you may have an issue with the **module-switch-on-port-available** loaded from the `default.pa` settings. You may try to [disable this module](https://askubuntu.com/a/228623/3940).

Comment: It only lists "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" as output devices, so I don't know what to do there. I can select HDMI in the "Configuration" tab though, but this doesn't help with my issue. I only have one audio device, but there are speakers and a flat screen (via HDMI) plugged in. By default the sound comes from the flat screen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a pulseaudio module (module-switch-on-connect) that when enabled, it may do exactly what is requested, as shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/158250/75657). It is a simple answer and works like a charm, seems in all Ubuntu versions from 12.04 till 17.04.