# When I unplug headphones, audio switches to HDMI out instead of laptop speakers

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, headphones

My HDMI port is connected to a VGA adaptor, so to get audio I have to manually switch the audio output to the speakers whenever I unplug my headphones. I've tested this with a mic'd headset and normal headphones and it happens with both. I've seen an answer to a similar question which suggests disabling the HDMI output in pavucontrol, but there's no option to do this.

Comment: See if this answer helps you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/432603/set-headphones-as-default-sound-output-defaults-to-hdmi/432609?r=SearchResults&s=1|37.4625#432609 (use built-in audio instead of headphones)

Comment: @Takkat I just tried that, but unplugging my headphones resets the fallback device to the HDMI output.

Comment: Sorry to hear. It used to be that with *pavucontrol* you could set the fallback device to built in audio, and that pulseaudio respected this, but if in your case if it still uses the HDMI it may be broken or it is another issue.