# How to prevent automatic change of the audio device?

Tags: gnome, sound, 17.10, settings

My Ubuntu 17.10 is connected via HDMI with my TV. HDMI ist the audio device I want **always** to use. Sometimes when the TV is turned off, Ubuntu switches the audio device tho semething else. When I turn on the TV again, I have to switch it back manually. How to prevent this automatic switching and set the audio device once and forever?

Comment: This should do what you need, by disabling the automatic output device switching, so that the output always stays on what you set it to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/228619/disable-sound-through-hdmi-permanently

Answer (score 18):

In `/etc/pulse/default.pa` comment out module-switch-on-port-available:

```
# load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

Then restart.

Answer (score 10):

You must deactivate all modules that start with `module-switch-on-*` in pulse audio service if you want to disable this behavior also with bluetooth and USB devices.

Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 LTS, for example:

- `module-switch-on-port-available`
- `module-switch-on-connect`

In a single instruction:

```
sudo sed -ri 's/^(load-module module-switch-on-.*$)/# \1/' /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Then kill pulse audio or reboot:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Witek's answer worked for me. I am new to Ubuntu (Xubuntu) so I didn't even know how to even comment out a line. So for people like me, here's a more detailed answer:

Go to your file manager and click "file system". Then find `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

Open that file using any text editor.

Putting a hash symbol `#` in front of a line of code is how you comment out a line. Put a hash in front of the line that reads:

```
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

When you click save, it will ask for your admin password. Enter it, restart and you're done.