# How to blacklist output and input devices?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I cant make a screenshot while the option menu is open, but in here:

[image]

I always have to reset my output device to "Headphones". It also contains HDMI output, "Scarlett SOLO Output Digital" and "Scarlett SOLO Output Analog" but I never use any of them. Can I disable those to avoid the hustle to select my headphones after every restart?

Same with my input device, I only use Scarlett Digital input, but not Scarlett Analog Input, nor my internal microphone, nor the microphone of my separate webcam. Ever.

Can I disable all of those options? I constantly have to go there and correct the selection.

Here is the list of my modules:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cdc_ether              20480  0
cdc_subset             16384  0
usbnet                 45056  2 cdc_subset,cdc_ether
mii                    20480  1 usbnet
xt_nat                 16384  14
xt_tcpudp              20480  18
veth                   28672  0
xt_conntrack           16384  6
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  8
nf_conntrack_netlink    45056  0
nfnetlink              16384  2 nf_conntrack_netlink
xfrm_user              36864  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            16384  2
iptable_filter         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  4
nf_nat                 40960  3 xt_nat,iptable_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack          139264  5 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,xt_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_nat
bpfilter               32768  0
br_netfilter           28672  0
bridge                176128  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
ccm                    20480  6
rfcomm                 81920  16
aufs                  262144  0
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 24576  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  2
overlay               114688  3
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_intel          53248  5
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_usb_audio         270336  2
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_usbmidi_lib        36864  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
kvm_amd                98304  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
ccp                    86016  1 kvm_amd
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
amdgpu               5373952  21
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_amd
nls_iso8859_1          16384  2
snd_rawmidi            36864  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  8
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdgpu
amd_sched              32768  1 amdgpu
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
amdttm                102400  1 amdgpu
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
rtwpci                 24576  0
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
rtw88                 618496  1 rtwpci
uvcvideo               98304  0
rtsx_pci_ms            24576  0
serio_raw              20480  0
mac80211              843776  2 rtwpci,rtw88
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
btusb                  57344  0
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
hid_multitouch         28672  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
btintel                24576  1 btusb
input_leds             16384  0
snd                    90112  27 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
bluetooth             581632  41 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
videodev              225280  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
joydev                 24576  0
mc                     53248  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
cfg80211              704512  2 mac80211,rtw88
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
typec_ucsi             40960  1 ucsi_acpi
amdkcl                 24576  2 amdttm,amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 amdgpu
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       20480  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ecc                    28672  1 ecdh_generic
k10temp                16384  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_pci_acp3x          16384  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
typec                  45056  1 typec_ucsi
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              24576  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          20480  1 lis3lv02d
mac_hid                16384  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   491520  11 drm_kms_helper,amd_sched,amdttm,amdgpu,amdkcl
ip_tables              32768  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               40960  7 xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_nat,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE
autofs4                45056  2
usbhid                 57344  0
mmc_block              49152  2
hid_generic            16384  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         28672  0
nvme                   49152  2
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ahci                   40960  0
i2c_piix4              28672  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
r8169                  90112  0
nvme_core             102400  4 nvme
rtsx_pci               73728  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
realtek                24576  1
wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof
video                  49152  0
i2c_hid                28672  0
hid                   131072  4 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
```

Comment: Blacklist applies to modules, so you need to identify which modules enable or activate the desired devices.

Comment: @darth_epoxy not sure what modules are

Comment: Open a terminal and type `lsmod` and it will return a large list. Look through that list for anything that resembles headphones, the other devices or Scarlett devices. Copy and paste just those lines (edit your question above to add those lines) and we will see what we've got.

Comment: @darth_epoxy I added the list of modules to my question. Could not identify ` Scarlett devices`.

Comment: Unfortunately there does not appear to be any specific modules that run your devices. Meaning that they are gereric usb, bluetooth or hid modules AND if you blacklist them then all of the hardware that require them will also cease to operate. I am no expert in this field so hopefully someone else in the community might help but it looks like a dead end to me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of blacklisting the output/input devices, one can disable the automatic audio change on startup:

In `/etc/pulse/default.pa` comment out module-switch-on-port-available:

```
# load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

Then restart.

Source: [How to prevent automatic change of the audio device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991484/how-to-prevent-automatic-change-of-the-audio-device)