# Ubuntu automatically unmutes sound in lockscreen

Tags: sound

I noticed today that the sound/music in a game I had running in the background was playing when the screen is locked. I tried muting the sound, and turning down the volume, which will mute the sound for a short time before it's back again. This behaviour will only occur when the screen is locked. As soon as I unlock it, it is muted like it should be.

Any ideas what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and solved by:

Comment line `load-module module-switch-on-port-available` from `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and then restart pulse with `pulseaudio -k`

Taken from: https://askubuntu.com/a/228623/654555

Comment: This did not solve the issue in my case (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS). I have the same problem when my laptop is connected to monitors through a docking hub. Nearly blew out my headphones and my ears because of this issue in Ubuntu.