# How to diagnose audio / sound problems

Tags: sound, hardware, pulseaudio, alsa

How can I diagnose audio / sound problems? Which informations should I provide to get help to identity the problem?

Comment: open a console and type `pulseaudio -k` and see if it helps

Comment: This question has a great response: http://askubuntu.com/questions/201780/how-do-i-debug-issues-with-pulse-audio