# No voice on front headphone port.

Tags: sound, 14.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have a strange problem. It just happen recently, when I accidentally unplug my headphone. But I unplugged it before and nothing happen. Basically now, when I use my headphone through front jack, when playing videos, I can't hear voice. Only background music. Using kde sound setup, pressing front left and front right test button, result in a mono sound. No distinction between right and left. This only happen with front jack. Rear jack is working fine.

Comment: See if guest account is working fine. If yes, try solutions from http://askubuntu.com/questions/201780/how-do-i-debug-issues-with-pulse-audio

Comment: I have the same problem. As a workaround, you can try shifting the headphone balance. When I set it all the way left or right, the sound seems OK.

Comment: Can you tell me what happens when you do a test sound on the Sound Settings window? In my case, whether I press "Front Left" or "Front Right", now I get sound coming out of both speakers.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I also had this problem when using my Apple 3.5mm headphone on Kubuntu, but when I held the volume up or down button, it had no effect on the actual volume, but my headphone had a sound.

To solve this problem, simply pull the plug a little and the sound will recover.

Probably because the top connector is for controlling audio input, but the input and output on the motherboard are separate, so you can't insert the wrong interface if you want to use the output function normally. Of course, the input function is not available when the output function is used normally.

Forgive me for my poor English, good luck

Answer (score 0):

- You can try to launch  "pulseaudio volume control" from multimedia  menu   then change profile in right tab (sound like you switch to a 5.1 profile)  .

  (if   "pulseaudio volume control" is not installed: sudo apt-get install pavucontrol)