# Sound not working; no devices show up; only for my user

Tags: sound, 15.04, pulseaudio, alsa

earlier today I tried to make my Asus SonicMaster subwoofer work on my laptop, and succeeded. However, that was after some trial and error of messing around with some sound settings. The issue now, is that after a reboot, the sound stopped working for me completely. I have looked around the internet for about 2 hours now, and honestly couldn't find anything that helped me. The interesting thing here is that the Ubuntu startup sound can be heard through my speakers on boot, and sound works flawlessly in a guest session. Obviously, it must just be a user thing. I have no devices under Output in sound settings. Plugging in headphones does nothing. I have tried running alsamixer in a terminal, but my internal speakers don't even have a bar for me to raise or lower. I honestly have looked around and have tried to fix it myself like I usually do, but I am simply stuck here. Also, the volume buttons don't work (with my user). They do work in a guest session, like I said. Does anyone have any ideas? Are there any command outputs I should include?

edit: I noticed that by running the hdajackretask command and setting my Realtek unconnected pin 0x1b to Internal Speaker LFE, it breaks the audio for my main user. If I were to remove that override feature, the sound is restored after logging out and in again. However, even if I have the override function on, sound will work for another user that I just made. (Yes, with the subwoofer working and everything.) So basically, I just want to be able to use my subwoofer on my main user account. Can anybody help at all? I really don't want to have to do a full reinstall of Ubuntu, but if that's what it takes if I don't get any answers, I guess that's what it takes.

Comment: See [my answer to this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/201780/how-do-i-debug-issues-with-pulse-audio) on possible solutions.