# Firefox starts in mute by default

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, volume-control

Firefox always starts at 0 vol as if that is supposed to be the default or something.

Any time I adjust the volume in firefox, I have to open pulse audio and turn the volume back up for firefox.

Any time a new video comes on Youtube, I have to open pulse audio and turn the volume back up for firefox.

Any time I skip forward or back in a playing video or track, I have to open pulse audio and turn the volume back up for firefox.

How can I set the default volume to FULL VOLUME?

I mean seriously, isn't that why there is a system volume?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be just a user setting in your `.config/pulse`. Try to remove it, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/201780/how-do-i-debug-issues-with-pulse-audio

Comment: @Takkat I tried that and it didn't work, however, I did find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution!

First, I opened firefox went to `about:config`

searched for: `media.default_volume`

double clicked `media.default_volume`

and finally, I changed the value to `5`

Additionally, I saw a solution somewhere else that suggested using `2.0` for `media.volume_scale`,

make sure that `media.volume_scale` is set to `1.0`

Comment: It solved the mute-on-pause-error in 78.14.0esr at debian 11 by setting: media.default_volume 10 and media.volume_scale 1.0

Comment: For the admins, please see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

In my system, Firefox for some reason did not have the permission to play sounds. To change it: right click on the icon of the app-> Show Details -> Click on the app -> Permissions -> play sound's check

[image]

Comment: This is actually a different issue. For my problem, I would have to increase the volume after starting firefox every time so the permissions were fine. I think the permission issue is for the snap version of firefox.

Comment: As commented [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2457405&s=01413d1caed4ce1e895cd7e04adf6f8d#post_14018310) on the ubuntu forums, *"The main advantage of snaps is that they're sandboxed. The main disadvantage of snaps is that they're sandboxed"*.