# How can I stop Firefox from dropping volume on new media?

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm not sure if other browsers or programs have this issue, but I've noticed it while using Firefox, on YouTube or Pandora. When a new video/track begins, the output audio of the browser (not the main volume) becomes lower. My guess is something trying to optimize sound quality, but when I'm making a bunch of noise, I need volume over quality. Pictured is my audio window showing the new Firefox audio being lower than it was before.

[image: screenshot of Playback tab in Volume Control]

Comment: you can find lots of similar bug reports like this https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1201925 it's been for a couple of years now.

Comment: also similar https://askubuntu.com/questions/967061/firefox-keeps-resetting-pulse-volume-to-0

Comment: I tried the delete /mozilla folder suggestion from the other topic. I had to reset all my passwords and bookmarks, but the problem persists. In fact it seems worse. What used to be a drop to 80% is now dropping to around 60%. The support link seems to be a solution for windows. I could not find an ubuntu solution there. @JoKer

Comment: I meant to say that it is a bug not only for Ubuntu and it's been happening for years so you'd better file it as a bug report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case someone comes across this question (as did I), there is an answer here: [Inconsistent Sound Volume Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257380/inconsistent-sound-volume-ubuntu-20-04)

Basically, you need to change `flat-volumes = no` to `flat-volumes = yes`.
The values "true", "1" and "on" are equivalent to "yes", according to the manpage (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/pulse-daemon.conf.5.html):

> For  the  settings  that  take  a  boolean  argument  the  values  true, yes, on and 1 are
> equivalent, resp. false, no, off, 0.

Don't forged to uncomment the respective line by removing the ";" or "#":

> The   configuration  file  is  a  simple  collection  of  variable  declarations.  If  the
> configuration file parser encounters either ; or # it ignores the rest of the  line  until
> its end.

The configuration file is: `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

Other possible locations are: `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf`,   `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf.d/*.conf` and `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf.d/*.conf`:

> The  PulseAudio  sound  server reads configuration directives from a configuration file on
> startup. If the per-user file ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf exists, it  is  used,  otherwise
> the  system  configuration  file /etc/pulse/daemon.conf is used. In addition to those main
> files,  configuration  directives  can  also   be   put   in   files   under   directories
> ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf.d/ and /etc/pulse/daemon.conf.d/.

According to the aforementioned post, **rebooting is necessary** for the change to take effect.

About the configuration option:

> flat-volumes=  Enable  'flat'  volumes,  i.e. where possible let the sink volume equal the
> maximum of the volumes of the inputs connected to it. Takes a boolean  argument,  defaults
> to no.

EDIT: I tested the solution myself and it worked (Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: sorry i was off this site for a long time. I can't really test this since i haven't had the problem in a while. But I'll take your word for it and mark it as answered.

Comment: Hahaha thank you for coming back

Comment: does not solve the issue with firefox