# Firefox volume keeps resetting to 40-50% when playing Youtube, existing solutions don't help

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, youtube, volume-control

I have recently begun having a very annoying issue with audio playback in Firefox 87 (Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity Desktop; application-based volumes are a thing there too), possibly due to a Firefox update (which I didn't notice, but I'm fairly sure the version number is higher). I had assumed that it was due to a number of other listed issues (such as [Inconsistent Sound Volume Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257380/inconsistent-sound-volume-ubuntu-20-04) or [Firefox keeps resetting Pulse volume to 0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967061/firefox-keeps-resetting-pulse-volume-to-0)), all of which I have tried.

However, I just noticed that the issue is *only* with Youtube videos (so far). In fact, the regular volume is being kept just fine (the example was a HTML5 music player) as shown in the first Firefox entry. The second one appears only while Youtube is being played, and apparently deletes itself or disappears and resets the volume to a bit less than 50% every time I pause or stop a video. This is playing merry hell with my audio preferences since I'm alternately deafened or unable to hear what I'm trying to watch.

[image: Youtube spawns a new Firefox application instance every time sound plays]

Does anyone have any ideas? I've even looked for "volume" in about:config and those seem normal...

(Also, is this spawning a bunch of configs in my audio settings app for all the new Firefox profiles? I'd hate to be accidentally filling up my precious SSD space with one-off never-to-be-used again audio profiles)

EDIT:
Here's the output of the command in the comments:

```
total 152
drwx------  2 dracos dracos  4096 Apr 30  2019 .
drwx------ 71 dracos dracos 20480 Apr 23 22:07 ..
-rw-------  1 dracos dracos   256 Sep 18  2017 cookie
-rw-r--r--  1 dracos dracos 40960 Apr 25 17:21 eb0493ce214748b3add5028fdff3fa37-card-database.tdb
-rw-r--r--  1 dracos dracos    39 Apr 26 01:35 eb0493ce214748b3add5028fdff3fa37-default-sink
-rw-r--r--  1 dracos dracos    49 Apr 26 01:35 eb0493ce214748b3add5028fdff3fa37-default-source
-rw-r--r--  1 dracos dracos 12288 Apr 26 10:55 eb0493ce214748b3add5028fdff3fa37-device-volumes.tdb
-rw-r--r--  1 dracos dracos 12288 Apr 26 12:15 eb0493ce214748b3add5028fdff3fa37-stream-volumes.tdb
```

Comment: `ls -al $HOME/.config/pulse` please add this to your question. Maybe helpful  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=196044

Comment: So I'm supposed to add some sort of file to that .config folder? Although that last post in the thread confuses me a bit. If this is the issue, can I have a list of steps? Thanks!

Comment: please can you check something first? `pacmd` then give in the cli `llist-modules` Is the part  <module-stream-restore>  loaded?

Comment: Yes. Also, there are 29 modules. Is that normal?