# Reduce bass / treble // Reset pulseaudio equalizer to default

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, equalizer

So I was messing with the equalizer then I realised there was no option to reset to default (And no flat doesnt sounds like EQ disabled) I just want to reduce the bass and treble. help please. Also I'm kind off too new to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which equalizer you use settings may be stored in `~/.pulse` or `~/.config/pulse`. In a standard Ubuntu setup any of these directories can be removed to restore defaults:

```
    mv ~/.pulse ~/.pulse.bad
```

or

```
    mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.bad  ## for newer releases
```

See [How do I debug issues with Pulse Audio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201780/how-do-i-debug-issues-with-pulse-audio)