# Audio Devices Disappear?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, 17.10, alsa

I just freshly installed Kubuntu 17.10 from a bittorrent image from the Kubuntu.org website, and this has regular audio, but upon a few restarts, audio devices disappear from the list, and there is no sound. There are no audio devices listed: 
[image: No Devices]
[image: No Devices Continued]
[image: Only Default]

I've tried the solutions from ([How do I debug issues with Pulse Audio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201780/how-do-i-debug-issues-with-pulse-audio)) and reached the following conclusions:

1) `pulseaudio -k` yields: `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process`

2) `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.bad  ## for newer releases` Yeilds no output. I assume that the move command executed without error.

3)`alsamixer` brings up the alsamixer control panel, although I'm not sure how to interpret if the channel is muted or not. Instead, I've made a video walking through the control panel. Maybe someone can tell me if I missed something. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VirImEtYxY4)

4) `pulseaudio -D` Fails: `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.`

5) `pulseaudio -vvvv` Log File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fc53mbap27dquw5/Audio%20Log?dl=0

6) `start-pulseaudio-x11` Yields:

> Connection failure: Connection refused
>
> pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

I can provide hardware specs upon demand, just tell me what to run. If you want me to execute commands, I'll be watching the post.

**Edit 0:** I haven't tried any solutions to the problem yet. Others recommend purging `pulse-audio` as others have recommended not doing that.

**Edit 1:** The issue isn't kernel related, I just used the advanced options menu when booting to go to the previous kernel version, and the problem still persists.

**Edit 2:** This problem is rather persistent, and will still occur after another fresh reinstall. It appears to happen at random, with no identifiable cause. Most times it will be fine, and then one restart of the system later, it will be buggy with no audio devices listed, and this state will then persist for all future restarts of the system.

**Edit 3: Hardware Info** 
[image: Hardware Info]

**Edit 4: Attempted Fix: Purge `pulseaudio` Then Reinstall It**

Had limited success. Sound restored, and some devices are back. I'm not sure if it works with bluetooth (I'll check later). There  is some buggy behavior left still. For instance, check the before and after pictures of `System Settings/Multimedia` one of the tabs is missing, also, the sound slider will not function. I subverted this by installing `kmix`, a substitute. I don't know the default package for the hardware volume slider or how to get the system back to a less buggy state.

[image: After Attempted Fix]

**EDIT 5:** It appears that the temporary measure weren't enough, and the audio bug is present again.

Answer (score 0):

Does the solution in "Known issues" in the 17.10 release notes not work for you?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu#pulseaudio_-_devices_not_showing.2Fpulseaudio_crash

Comment: Uncertain, haven't tried it yet. Just tried it, we'll see...