# Trying to solve a NO SOUND issue in Unity on 14.04. Sound Settings now unstable

Tags: 14.04, unity, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

If I focus on  'Analogue Output built-in audio' in Sound Settings the dialogue becomes unstable -  very rapidly toggling between 'Analogue Output built-in audio' and 'Headphones built-in audio' but 'Digital Output (S/PDIF) built-in audio' is stable and available but there is no sound from any source. I have tried several un/reinstalls however still no sound and the toggling persists.

Comment: If a hardware issue (headphone jack loose?) is excluded [you can try with these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/202533/3940).

Comment: No headphone plugged in - I don't use headphones on this PC - worked through https://askubuntu.com/questions/201780/how-do-i-debug-issues-with-pulse-audio/202533#202533 [thanks!] :- No output once alsa crashed pulsaudio:- 'pulseaudio -D' gives 'E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed'. Will reboot in a minute and try again.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `alsamixer`command in your terminal and unmute all

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - in a Terminal typed 'alsamixer' . Despite having set everything  to 'OO' [output] yesterday I find all outputs set to MM [mute] except 'Front Mic', 'line' and 'CD'. I reset various combinations to 'OO': I get sound for a while, but interrupted by awful scratching [in time with the toggling mentioned above]. When I try to mute 'Headphones' all indicators are muted and all sound is lost and cannot be retrieved. Will now try @Takkat 's kind suggestions above.

Comment: Some days later: the toggling problem has just gone away and alsamixer now functions ok but there is still no sound. I have not knowingly altered anything just booted up several times so this is a comment rather than an answer to whatever the problem was.

Comment: for me alsamixer worked