# Audio Not Working on Ubuntu 16.04 (I have tried everything)

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Just yesterday, everything was fine.  Previously, only my input devices would not work. Now nothing works.

I have checked Alsamixer.
I have purged and reinstalled Pulseaudio.
I have rebooted my device countless times.
I have changed my sound card, including external and internal sound cards.
I have unmuted everything, volume is full.
I have tried different browsers and playing files from my desktop itself.

Please somebody help.

Comment: Did you try to [remove the user settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/202533/3940) too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How do I do that?

Comment: Click on above [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/202533/3940) . My answer there is more elaborate than a comment could ever be.